# Passing pointers to DLL function in Python

Tags: python, dll

I am working on a project where I have to build a GUI for a development board with python with which I am new to as well. I am given the DLL which has required functions to communicate with the development board.
I have LabVIEW equivalent function prototype which looks something like this:

```
int32_t WriteFPGARegsC(int16_t *USBdev, int32_t *DUTSelect, int32_t *Array_RegsIn, int32_t *Array_RegsOut, int32_t *Array_RegEnable);
```

And the same prototype also looks like this for Visual Basic:

```
Public Declare Function WriteFPGARegsC Lib "USB_IO_for_VB6.dll" (ByRef USBdev As Short, ByVal DUTSelect As Integer, ByRef Array_RegsIn As Integer, ByRef Array_RegsOut As Integer, ByRef Array_RegEnable As Integer) As Integer
```

I am trying to access this function with python instead of LabVIEW because of a lot of issues.

Last three parameters to be passed to the function needs to be an address to an array of 255 elements.

**I have no clue how to pass pointers in function in python!!**

I wrote the following shortcode to access this function in python:

```
USBdev = [0]
DUTSelect = [0]
RegsIn = [0] * 255
RegsOut = [0] * 255
RegEnable = [0] * 255

from ctypes import*

mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("USB_IO_for_VB6.dll")
retmydll = mydll.WriteFPGARegsC(USBdev, DUTSelect, RegsIn, RegsOut, RegEnable)
```

After executing this code I get following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Kushal\ATLASS\Source_code\Atlass.py", line 12, in <module>
    retmydll = mydll.WriteFPGARegsC(id(USBdev), id(DUTSelect), id(RegsIn),    id(RegsOut), id(RegEnable))
ValueError: Procedure called with not enough arguments (20 bytes missing) or wrong calling convention
```

Any help will be appreciated!!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [[Python]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) states, there are a few things to do, out of which the most important is setting `argtypes` and `restype` for the function object. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com) is full of similar questions (I answered to several of them).

Anyway, I prepared a dummy example (don't mind the error proneness), it's just for illustrating the mechanism.

*code.c*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define DIM 10  // Must be the SAME (well, or lower) than the constant defined in the Python code


__declspec(dllexport) int32_t __stdcall WriteFPGARegsC(int16_t *USBdev, int32_t *DUTSelect, int32_t *Array_RegsIn, int32_t *Array_RegsOut, int32_t *Array_RegEnable) {
    int32_t ret = 99;
    printf("From C:\n\t*USBdev: %d\n\t*DUTSelect: %d\n\tArray_RegsIn[0]: %d\n\tArray_RegsOut[0]: %d\n\tArray_RegEnable[0]: %d\n\n\tReturning: %d\n",
    *USBdev, *DUTSelect, Array_RegsIn[0], Array_RegsOut[0], Array_RegEnable[0], ret);
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        Array_RegsOut[i] *= *DUTSelect;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

*code.py*:

```
import sys
import ctypes


DIM = 10  # Should be 255, but for demo purposes keep it smaller
uint_arr = ctypes.c_uint * DIM
ushort_arr = ctypes.c_ushort * DIM
uint_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint)
ushort_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ushort)


def main():
    dll = ctypes.WinDLL("USB_IO_for_VB6.dll")
    func = dll.WriteFPGARegsC
    func.argtypes = [ushort_p, uint_p, uint_p, uint_p, uint_p]
    func.restype = ctypes.c_uint

    usb_dev = ctypes.c_ushort(25)
    dut_select = ctypes.c_uint(2)
    regs_in = uint_arr(*range(20, 20 + DIM))
    regs_out = uint_arr(*range(30, 30 + DIM))
    reg_enable = uint_arr(*range(40, 40 + DIM))

    nth = 5
    print("Output register array: {:s}".format(" ".join(["{:d}".format(item) for item in regs_out])))
    print("\tIts {:d}th element: {:d}\n".format(nth, regs_out[nth]))

    ret = func(ctypes.byref(usb_dev), ctypes.byref(dut_select), regs_in, regs_out, reg_enable)
    print("\nFunction returned: {:d}".format(ret))
    print("Output register array: {:s}".format(" ".join(["{:d}".format(item) for item in regs_out])))
    print("\tIts {:d}th element: {:d}\n".format(nth, regs_out[nth]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Output**:

> ```
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q051289410>"c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\vc\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
>
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q051289410>dir /b
> code.c
> code.py
>
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q051289410>cl /nologo code.c /link /DLL /OUT:USB_IO_for_VB6.dll
> code.c
>    Creating library USB_IO_for_VB6.lib and object USB_IO_for_VB6.exp
>
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q051289410>dir /b
> code.c
> code.obj
> code.py
> USB_IO_for_VB6.dll
> USB_IO_for_VB6.exp
> USB_IO_for_VB6.lib
>
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q051289410>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Output register array: 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
>         Its 5th element: 35
>
> From C:
>         *USBdev: 25
>         *DUTSelect: 2
>         Array_RegsIn[0]: 20
>         Array_RegsOut[0]: 30
>         Array_RegEnable[0]: 40
>
>         Returning: 99
>
> Function returned: 99
> Output register array: 60 62 64 66 68 70 72 74 76 78
>         Its 5th element: 70
> ```

***@EDIT0***:

- Modified answer to be as close as possible to the real scenario, and also to address questions in the comments

  - To make it clear, a *ctypes* array can be accessed as any other *Python* sequence

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's quite helpful. Just one issue: First two arguments are just pointers but not array pointers. Also when i tried to execute your code i code error: ret = func(usb_dev, dut_select, regs_in, regs_out, reg_enable)
ValueError: Procedure called with not enough arguments (20 bytes missing) or wrong calling convention

Comment: Although argument names support your statement, their type (`uint32_t*`) doesn't as they are all pointers. Are you sure you posted the correct function signature? Just the eliminate the other factor, in the *Python* code (as it is in my answer) replace the line `dll = ctypes.CDLL("USB_IO_for_VB6.dll")` by `dll = ctypes.WinDLL("USB_IO_for_VB6.dll")` and see if there is any difference.

Comment: Worked after i changed to WinDLL!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: One short question....How do I access those arrays that I passed to the function!!

Comment: I edited the question shortly after you asked. Take a look a the `print`s (I am accessing `regs_out` elements). and the comments. You can access it as a list, e.g. `array[index]` or as an iterable: `for item in array:`.

Comment: Thanks a lot again!! One last request!! I have to initialize all the arrays to zero!! That's the requirement for the DLL!! Any clue how I do that!!

Comment: `regs_in = uint_arr()`. Hmm, strange you couldn't figure this out from the code (and doc).

Comment: Sorry!! I am not an advanced python user!! But how do I initialize the arrays with 255 zeros? Really sorry for bothering you!!

Comment: I've just explained in my previous comment.