# How to call a C function with an output parameter

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

A have code in my dll (on C++). The function must accept a pointer to `long` as an output variable:

```
int add(int a, long *ddd)
{   
    *ddd = 1758;
    return a;
}
```

I am using Python 3:

```
from ctypes import *
import os

adr = os.getcwd()
dll = CDLL(adr + '\mydllcode.dll')

myint = 999
mylong = c_long(8888)
p_myint = c_int(myint)
p_mychar = c_wchar_p(mychar)
p_mylong = POINTER(mylong)

dll.add.argtypes = [c_int, POINTER(c_long)]
ret = dll.sub(p_myint, p_mylong)
print(ret)
print(str(mylong) + ' - ' + p_mylong.value)
```

And I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PythonProjects\Shield\testdll.py", line 12, in <module>
p_mylong = POINTER(mylong)
TypeError: unhashable type
```

Answer (score 1):

`POINTER(ctypes-type)` declares a pointer *type* and its parameter must be a `ctypes` type, so below was incorrect:

```
mylong = c_long(8888)        # Creates a ctypes instance, not a type.
p_mylong = POINTER(mylong)  # error
```

When you create a ctype to hold the output parameter, simply create an instance of the type:

```
mylong = c_long()  # defaults to a value of zero, but for output parameter doesn't matter
```

Then pass it as a parameter by reference with:

```
byref(mylong)
```

Also, wrapping input values is generally unncessary if you set `.argtypes`.  `ctypes` knows to wrap Python values as declared, so you can just pass them directly.

Example:

**test.c**

```c
__declspec(dllexport)
int add(int a, long *ddd)
{   
    *ddd = 1758;
    return a;
}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct

dll = ct.CDLL('./test') # look in current directory for DLL.
dll.add.argtypes = ct.c_int,ct.POINTER(ct.c_long)
dll.add.restype = ct.c_int

mylong = ct.c_long() # instance to store output variable
ret = dll.add(999,ct.byref(mylong))  # pass by reference
print(ret,mylong.value)  # .value extracts the result as a Python object.
```

Output:

```
999 1758
```

You can create pointers directly with `pointer(instance`) as well, so below also works, but is less efficient than `byref`:

```py
import ctypes as ct

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
dll.add.argtypes = ct.c_int,ct.POINTER(ct.c_long) # pointer type. Note upper case!
dll.add.restype = ct.c_int

mylong = ct.c_long()          # create ctypes instance
p_mylong = ct.pointer(mylong) # create pointer to instance.  Note lower case!
ret = dll.add(999,p_mylong)
print(ret,mylong.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a little to Change the definitions to match.  Following the ideas in the answer to [Passing pointers to DLL function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51289410/passing-pointers-to-dll-function-in-python) , this may help

```
from ctypes import *
import os

adr = os.getcwd()
dll = CDLL(adr + '\mydllcode.dll')

myint = 999
mylong = c_long(8888)
p_myint = c_int(myint)
p_mychar = c_wchar_p(mychar)
p_mylong_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_long)

dll.add.argtypes = [c_int, p_mylong_p]
ret = dll.sub(p_myint, ctypes.byref(mylong))
print(ret)
print(str(mylong) + ' - ' + p_mylong.value)
```